# Organising cython source files and their tests (with nosetests)

Tags: python, cython, nose

When playing with [nose](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose/) and trying to combine it with [cython](http://cython.org) I can't quite get it all to work the way I'd like.  The code is organised like this:

```
.
├── setup.py
└── src
    ├── calc
    │   ├── factorial.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── tests.py
    └── cycalc
        ├── tests.py
        └── triangle.pyx
```

Each of the `tests.py` contains 2 tests, one succeeds, one fails.  The result of running `setup.py nosetests` is that only `calc/tests.py` are run.  If I after this run `nosetests3 src/cycalc` the two tests in `cycalc/tests.py` are run.  However, if I clean up all build files it fails because `cycalc/triangle.pyx` hasn't been built into a shared lib.

Then I tried adding the file `src/cycalc/__init__.py`, now `setup.py nosetests` picks up `cycalc/tests.py` but it fails to find the required module, it was placed in `src`.

How do I arrange my cython source and tests to make `setup.py nosetests` find everything it needs?

Answer (score 1):

For `nose` to run your tests automatically you should add them into a folder called tests containing all your tests. Like this:

```
.
|-setup.py
|-src
|---calc
|------factorial.py
|------__init__.py
|---cycalc
|------triangle.pyx
|------__init__.py
|-tests
|---__init__.py
|---test_calc.py    
|---test_cycalc.py
```

This way both tests will be run automatically with everything in the same path. If you remove the built files you need to run `python setup.py build` before the tests will work again.